# How to suppress columns from Manage Group search results

Tags: custom-templates

I'm customizing a version of the Manage Groups page. Users don't want to see Description, Group Type, or Visibility. I thought I could just customize a version of Group/Form/Search.tpl .

It's easy to suppress the column headers by commenting out the  tags. I need help learning how to suppress the actual  tags though. I can't make sense of the js in that template.

Answer (score 3):

I just learned how to use bVisible = false to suppress columns. I found what I needed at http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns, the columns documentation for datatable plugin.